# Integral kernel of Hilbert-Schmidt operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Every compact operator $A: L^2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$ can be expressed in canonical form as
$$
A=\sum_n p_n \left<\phi_n,\cdot\right> \psi_n,
$$
where $\{\phi_n\}$ and $\{\psi_n\}$ are (not necessarily complete) orthonormal sets and $\{p_n\}$ is a sequence of positive numbers with $p_n\rightarrow 0$. If additionally $\{p_n\}$ is square summable, then $A$ is Hilbert-Schmidt operator. We know that every Hilbert-Schmidt operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ has integral kernel $K(x,y)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$, but is it true in general that 
$$
K_A(x,y)=\sum_n p_n \psi_n(x)\overline{\phi}_n(y)
$$
is the integral kernel of operator $A$? Do you know any books or papers touching upon this problem?